# How can I most performantly display musical chord sheets in HTML5?

Tags: html, svg

I am currently working on my final year project for my degree in Software Engineering. I have decided that my project will be to develop a web application using HTML5 that will display chord sheets in a web browser (specifically Google Chrome). The idea is that each member of a band might have some sort of device in front of them (iPad, laptop etc.) which can access the application where they can log in, view the chords for the songs as the progress through a set and add annotations which are stored in the database and then shown to the user each time the song is displayed on their screem.

However, I am having a problem with how best to display all this in a browser window. I want it to have a similar appearance to that of a PDF document displayed in a browser window in that the user is able to scroll horizontally and vertically and zoom in and out as if they were viewing a PDF document. Is using SVG graphics the best way to achieve this? Or is there another way?

Rendering speed is going to be important as the idea is that this will be a system that could potentially be used in live situation, and I need to make sure I keep page loading/rendering times as low as possible.

I would greatly appreciate any thoughts you have!

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Vexflow](http://www.vexflow.com/)! It’s an [open-source](https://github.com/0xfe/vexflow) web-based music notation rendering API, written completely in JavaScript, and runs right in the browser. VexFlow supports HTML5 canvas and SVG.

[Here’s a demo](http://www.vexflow.com/) and [here’s a tutorial](http://www.vexflow.com/docs/tutorial.html).

Comment: Thanks, that does look good and may prove to be quite useful at some point, although I'm wanting to display lyrics/chords rather than music notation in this case.